# Extract data from cvent via Python

Tags: c#, python, pandas, soap

I really need to access data from cvent via python. Specifically, cvent utilizes SOAP. I have created a custom report in the cvent GUI for a specific event. Now, I would like to call the event data and render in a pandas dataframe. developers.cvent.com only provides C# code snips... which you guessed it, I know nothing about.

Thank you so much for the guidance in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this using the Python zeep package. Here's an example.

```
from datetime import datetime
from zeep import Client

#set account, user, password...
wsdl = 'https://api.cvent.com/soap/V200611.ASMX?WSDL'
client = Client(wsdl)
login_result = client.service.Login(account, user, password)
client.set_default_soapheaders({'CventSessionHeader': login_result.CventSessionHeader})

object_type = client.get_type("ns1:CvObjectType")('Event')
startdate = datetime(2019, 11, 20)
enddate = datetime(2019, 11, 21)
ids = client.service.GetUpdated(object_type, startdate, enddate).body.GetUpdatedResult.Id
objects = client.service.Retrieve(ObjectType=object_type, Ids=client.get_type("ns1:IdArray")(ids))
```

Note, it is important to declare parameter names when using the "Retrieve" service. It took me a while to figure this out.

Zeep will return data objects in json format, which is a much nicer way to work with the data. There are options in the zeep library to change the return format.